# Mongoose: Populating object's nested array with projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
var CarSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    partIds: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Part'}],
});

var PartSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    props: [
        { colour: {type: String}, shape: {type:String} }
    ],
});
```

For example

```
Car = {
       name: "BMW",
       partIds:[ObjectId("57baa43e152654f80aac36a6")]}

Part = {
        _id: ObjectId("57baa43e152654f80aac36a6"),
        name: "Piston",
        props: [{colour:"red", shape: "Cubical"},{colour:"green", shape: "cylindrical"}]
```

So when I query I should get a doc like this:

```
Car = {
      name: "BMW",
      partIds: [{ 
_id:ObjectId("57baa43e152654f80aac36a6"), name:"Piston", props: [{colour:"red", shape:"cubical"}]
     }
```

The props array should only have element with colour red

I want to populate Car with Part Array such that its prop array only have the object with colour red. Is there anyway to do it, or would I have to go old fashioned way and loop through props array matching its colour with red.

Comment: Do you already have the `part` Collection? Or do you create it and store its id in `car` Collection?

Comment: Part collection is different and its Ids are stored in Car collections' partIds

Comment: so you want to create `part` document and store its id in `car` collection if the color is red?

Comment: No, I want to query the Car collection such that it populate partIds such that props aray only have elements whose colour is red.

Comment: Added sample docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by providing the `select` option in your [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) call:

```
Car.findOne()
    .populate({
        path: 'partIds',
        select: { props: { $elemMatch: { colour: 'red' } }, name: 1 }
    })
    .exec(callback);
```

Result:

```
{ _id: 57c085451cd8dfcdf814f640,
    name: 'BMW',
    partIds:
     [ { _id: 57baa43e152654f80aac36a6,
         name: 'Piston',
         props: [ { colour: 'red', shape: 'Cubical' } ] } ] }
```

The `select` uses the [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) projection operator to select just the red `props` element.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it should get you what you want.

```
car.find({"partIds.props.colour" : "red"})
    .populate('partIds')
    .exec(function(err,result){...});
```